# Adding elements to a list without having duplicates using random generator

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

The goal of my task is to generate a presents list(with a max amount price) with presents from another list. The max amount(totalePrijs) cannot exceed 500 AND you can't have the same present more than once in that generated list. The presents chosen are done with a random generator that goes up to 27(amount of presents).

It works perfectly except for the same present more than once part. Which I have yet to figure out. Either I was thinking of making an empty IntegerArray and checking if that Array contained x, if it did than it should restart from the beginning of the while statement otherwise it would add x to that array and continue.

The other way I thought off was changing the if statement to

```
if (selectedCadeauModel.contains(present.name) && totalePrijs + present.price < 500)
```

But that just made it loop infinitly I think.

This is the code that executes when clicking on the generate presents button.

```
selectedCadeauModel.clear();         
      double totalePrijs = 0;

    while (totalePrijs < 500) {
        NumberGen ran = new NumberGen();
        int x = Integer.parseInt(ran.toString());            
        Cadeau present = (Cadeau) cadeauModel.elementAt(x);
        if (totalePrijs + present.price < 500) {
            totalePrijs += present.price;
            selectedCadeauModel.addElement(new Cadeau(present.name, present.price));
        } else {
            break;
        }            
        ftxTotaalPrijs.setValue(totalePrijs);
        lstGeneratedPresents.setModel(selectedCadeauModel);
        ftxGemiddeldePrijs.setValue(totalePrijs / selectedCadeauModel.size());
    }
```

/

```
public class Cadeau {

String name;
double price;

public Cadeau(String naam, double prijs) {
    name = naam;
    price = prijs;
}
```

/

```
public class NumberGen {

Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int getal = randomGenerator.nextInt(27);

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%d", getal);
}
}
```

Comment: `present.name` will never be equal to any instance of `Cadeau`, you will need to manually search the list yourself to find any possible matches.  You could override `equals` and `hashcode` of the `Cadeau` class to return appropriate values, this might make it easier to use things like `contains`

Comment: The most common/best way to do this is to shuffle the other list using [`Collections.shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-), and then grab the first N values in the list.

Comment: What is the type of `cadeauModel` and `selectedCadeauModel`? How many distinct values can be present in cadeauModel? The infinite loop could be resulting because at most you can have first 27 records picked from `cadeauModel`, but if these 27 records can't fill up the price of 500 then the loop is bound to repeat but never select any record because the uniqueness is conflicting. To provide moreinfo please tell the types of these 2 data set and how many records can be present in the first list. Also, What should happen in a scenario where price is not 500 but first 27 records are completed?

Comment: It should be `if not contains && ...` otherwise I would follow as MadProgrammer has suggested and override the `equals` and `hashcode` methods.